# View SQLite data with ViewPage

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-viewpager

I am trying to use a ViewPage to display some data like names of student from SQLite. It works well when I display the information on a listview. Now I want to view each student record in a ViewPage where a page only contains one student record. I fetched the information form the SQLite and put it in a list but I was unable to display it in the ViewPage.

Here is my OnCreateView Method:

```
public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)  
     View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    TextView textView=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_Label);

   //I used the code bellow to display the data on listView which worked fine
   //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

  // I now try to the the following to display it on ViewPage
  List<String> quotes=databaseAccess.getQuotes//I the getQuotes class is bellow

  textView.setText(quotes);//I assume this suppose to put each of the list element in the PageView
```

My getQuotes Class is :

```
public List<String> getQuotes()  {
     List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
     Cursor cursor= database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quotes", null;
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
           list.add(cursor.getString(0));
           cursor.moveToNext();
     }
     cursor.close();
     return list;
   }
   }
```

Please I need help. I'm doing it in the wrong way or I need to adjust something. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the textView displaying in your case?

Comment: Just names of student

Comment: If you changed 'List' to 'ArrayList' you could try to use quotes.get(i), where 'i' is an index in the list. Now you can set the textView on each Page using that. All you then have to do is manually increase the 'i' for each Page.

Comment: no i mean what is this `textView.setText(quotes);` displaying you right now with your implementation